# ITextSharp: Remove "scroll long text" from a form field

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I would like to programatically remove the "scroll long text" field from a form field in a PDF prior to stamping that field.  I would like to do so anytime a field has this setting enabled for a given form field.  I had a similar problem recently and had resolved this using the solution I posted at the bottom of this post: [ITextSharp: Remove character Limit from a form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215119/itextsharp-remove-character-limit-from-a-form-field/10222175#10222175)

I think I should be able to do this in the same area but I'm not sure which PdfName setting I need to be looking for to detect (and remove) this setting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), section `12.7.4.3`, **Interactive Features -> Interactive Forms -> Field Types -> Text Fields** you want to set the field flag (`Ff`) value. This value is a bitwise flag with position 24 being the "DoNotScroll" flag. Position 24 would be binary `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` or hex `0x800000`. Using this and the code from the other post you can add this and it should do what you're looking for:

```
if (AnnotationDictionary.Contains(PdfName.FF)) {
    int Ff = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsNumber(PdfName.FF).IntValue;
    int doNotScrollBit = 0x800000;
    Ff = doNotScrollBit | Ff;
    AnnotationDictionary.Put(PdfName.FF, new PdfNumber(Ff));
}
```