# Add file with bookmark

Tags: itext

I want to add a PDF file using iTextSharp but if PDF file contains bookmarks then they should also be added.

Currently I'm using following code

```
Document document = new Document();
//Step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create));
writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines;
//Step 3: Open the document
document.Open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

//The current file path
string filename = "D:\\rtf\\2.pdf";

// we create a reader for the document
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);

//Chapter ch = new Chapter("", 1);

for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < reader.NumberOfPages + 1; pageNumber++)
{
    document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    document.NewPage();

    // Insert to Destination on the first page
    if (pageNumber == 1)
    {
        Chunk fileRef = new Chunk(" ");
        fileRef.SetLocalDestination(filename);
        document.Add(fileRef);
    }

    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
    int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageNumber);
    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
    {
        cb.Add(page);
    }
    else
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }
}

document.Close();
```

Comment: Have you considered using a PdfStamper working on that original PDF with outlines to add your additional contents? A PdfStamper keeps all outlines and all interactive features of the original...

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/84/iTextSharp-Links-and-Bookmarks

Comment: what language are you programming in? - c sharp?

Comment: it might be worth looking at this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140339/using-itextsharp-to-extract-and-update-links-in-an-existing-pdf/8141831#8141831

Comment: this is an example of using pdfstamper http://wskidmore.com/2011/04/exporting-and-importing-pdf-bookmarks-itextsharp/

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Chapter 6 of my book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). In table 6.1, you'll read:

> Can import pages from other PDF documents. The major downside is that all interactive features of the imported page (annotations, bookmarks, fields, and so forth) are lost in the process.

This is exactly what you experience. However, if you look at the other classes listed in that table, you'll discover PdfStamper, PdfCopy, etc... which are classes that do preserve interactive features.

`PdfStamper` will keep the bookmarks. If you want to use `PdfCopy` (or `PdfSmartCopy`), you need to read chapter 7 to find out how to keep them. Chapter 7 isn't available for free, but you can consult the examples here: [Java](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=7) / [C#](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/513/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/). You need the [`ConcatenateBookmarks`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141) example.

Note that you're code currently looks convoluted because you're not using the correct classes. Using `PdfStamper` should significantly reduce the number of lines of code.