# Convert Html to PDF with link to a specific location in another PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm converting a group of HTML files to PDF in C#.
Wkhtmltopdf did the job perfectly, but now I need to add a link to a location in another pdf and wkhtmltopdf doesn't seem to be able to do that.

Creating links to point to another location in the same document is easy:

```
<a href="#idOfDesiredPlace">Link</a>
```

Also, linking to another document works well:

```
<a href="b.pdf">Link</a>
```

However, **I need to link to a specific location in a different document**. 
The simple method with wkhtmltopdf **fails** here:

```
<a href="b.pdf#idOfDesiredLocation">This link doesn't work</a>
```

This is supported in PDF specification with Remote Go-To actions.
[PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf), p. 520:
[image: remote go-to actions]

How can this be achieved in C#?

I need the converter to support CSS 3, so I think the way to go would be to first convert the HTML to PDF with wkhtmltopdf and then use a library to edit the PDF to correct the links.

How to do this practically? Which library to use and how to use it?

**UPDATE**:
I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4244) for wkhtmltopdf on GitHub. However, this question is still relevant.

Comment: Helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17812299/628637

Comment: I came across a library to do this called `Quick PDF library` by Debenu. Here's the link to the exact method https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/AddLinkToFile.php

Comment: When this problem seems not solvable in pure C# you can at least start a process with ghostscript to do this job.