# How to update a PDF object in C# using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, hyperlink, itext

I'm working with iTextSharp to read all the hyperlinks from a PDF document, but I also need to change their value. I'm getting all the objects of the PDF using a for loop and with that I can access to all of them, this is the code in PDF document:

```
74 0 obj<</F 75 0 R/S/Launch>>
endobj
75 0 obj(../documents/referenced_document.html)
endobj
76 0 obj<</F 77 0 R/S/Launch>>
endobj
```

And this is my code in C# to read the PDF Object:

```
PdfString pdfString = (PdfString)objectItem;
string innerText = pdfString.ToString();
```

My question is, how can I change the PsfString value that I get in the innerText string?
I've searched in the properties and methods of the PdfString and PdfObject classes,  but I can't find something that allow me to do that.

Does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: Did you see this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141831/231316