# Replace content inte a PDF File

Tags: pdf

The system I'm working with are receiving PDF documents, inside those documents there are two clickable images. The click events just triggers a http url. The thing is that I need to update those two url:s when I receive the document.

So my question is, is it possible to find the events and change the url and then save the file again? Those two images can be anywhere in the document so I can't look in a specific location.

Edit: I forgot to say that I'm coding in C# so it needs to be a .NET library.

Comment: Which PDF tools / libraries are you prepared to use?

Comment: Thats sort of the question, but I'm allowed to use any free 3rd party library. And I missed it in my question, I'm coding in C# so it needs to be a .NET library.

I do have a Telerik license so if they have anything in their suit that I can use I'm more thant pleased

Comment: Any generic .Net PDF library should allow you your task. ITextSharp coming to my mind while @Bobrovsky would surely think of Docotic, but there are others, too. I'd recommend selecting a PDF library first (licensing details may differ greatly) and then revise your question to target a solution for that library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just want to tell you how I solved this problem, or rather where I found the solution. I used the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140339/using-itextsharp-to-extract-and-update-links-in-an-existing-pdf) thread, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

It's hard to describe the way it can be achieved without knowing how PDFs are constructed (there are a few ways to create the described behavior) and tools you are going to use.

Comment: Do you know anywhere I can start reading about it and a library that has the needed functionallity? I understand that it can be hard to explain, but I need to start somewhere.